# Parsing text to a mysql table with characters to determine destination fields

Tags: java, php, mysql, edi, x12

I need a little guidance. I am attempting to parse data to a MySQL database. The file is delimited by '*' and each sequence begins with a 3 character marker and is terminated by a '~' .

```
CLP*71748-357266*1*12.59*12.59**13*01   122314 09284 00001*15~
NM1*QC*1*BARBOR*KELLY****MI*16372439510~
NM1*IL*1*BARBOR*KELLY****MI*16372439510~
NM1*82*2*ALL INCLUSIVE DAY PROGRAM*****XX*3789014207~
REF*1W*16372439510~REF*1J*D100195~
SVC*HC:T2048*12.59*12.59**1~
DTM*472*20141215~REF*6R*366762~
REF*RB*FDUL~
AMT*B6*12.59~
```

Anyone know where I should start? I was hoping I could do a select case statement in java script or something.

Comment: it would help if you also posted the result you are looking for, that is, what your data would look like after it has been successfully parsed

Comment: Java (tag) is not JavaScript (question) - what are you using?

Comment: you should buy a translator that will allow for mapping for this document to the database directly.  you are reinventing the wheel.  You get the delimiters from the ISA.  There are three: segment, element, sub-element. The ISA is fixed length so you get your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$text = 'Your text';

$arrayLines = explode('~',$text);

foreach($arrayLines as $line){

    $arrayString = explode('*',$line) //Here you get each string 

    //Based on your requirement do your logic here      
}
```